# I have this issue with script: TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable

Tags: python, selenium, object, iterable

I am having a problem executing this script:

```
pic_hrefs = [elem.get_attribute('a href') for elem in hrefs]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IB.py", line 56, in <module>
    kidCudix.like_photo('comfort')
  File "IB.py", line 41, in like_photo
    pic_hrefs = [elem.get_attribute('a href') for elem in hrefs]
TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You haven't shown what `hrefs` is

Comment: `get_attribute` return single string, you can't iterate over it. Not to mention in your case it will return `None`, there is no attribute `a href`. Try `href`.

Comment: @Guy, it's true that the attribute is incorrect and will cause an error, but that's not the error he is hitting (yet).  The OP is not trying to iterate over the result of `get_attribute`.

Comment: @Guy, nope, it would iterate over `hrefs` and apply `get_attrbute` to each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `elem.get_attribute('a href')` is problematic since `'a href'` is not a valid attribute.  Instead, you want to use `elem.get_attribute('href')`.

However, that's not the error you are hitting.

The error message (`TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable`) implies that your input iterable (`hrefs`) is of the type `FirefoxWebElement`, which can't be used with a list comprehension since a single `FirefoxWebElement` is not iterable. Instead of a single element, you need to use a *list* of elements in your list comprehension. (A list comprehension creates a list from another input iterable).  Your comprehension should be something like:

```
hrefs = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elements]
```

Example:

The question is vague, but you are likely trying to create a list of links on a web page. To get a list of all links, the general pattern is:

- create a webdriver
- navigate to a page
- locate all elements that represent anchor tags
- extract the `href` attribute from each element and store them in a list

You could do that with code like:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://some_url')
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
hrefs = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elements]
```

Notice that `find_elements_by_tag_name('a')` returns a *list* of `WebElement`, which I use in the subsequent list comprehension.  Also notice that the method used is `find_elements_by_tag_name` (plural).  This differs from `find_element_by_tag_name` (singular) which would only locate a single element.